# Exclusive customers to one item in one category who buy more in period 2 vs period 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: products and orders

```
CREATE TABLE product (
   product_id INTEGER,
   product_name CHARACTER VARYING(20),
   category_name CHARACTER VARYING(20)
);

CREATE TABLE  orders (
   order_id  INTEGER,
   date_id INTEGER,
   customer_id INTEGER,
   product_id INTEGER,
   sales INTEGER   
 );
```

Here is some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO product VALUES (1,'widget','thingamabobs'); 
INSERT INTO product VALUES (2,'sprocket','thingamabobs'); 
INSERT INTO product VALUES (3,'gizmo','doodads'); 

-- 10 orders across 2 dates to 5 customers

INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1,1,1,1,2); 
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1,1,1,3,2); 
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (2,1,2,2,3); 
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (3,1,3,1,1); 
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (4,1,4,1,2);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (5,1,5,1,1);
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (6,2,1,1,3); 
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (6,2,1,3,2); 
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (7,2,2,2,3); 
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (8,2,3,1,1); 
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (8,2,3,2,1); 
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (9,2,4,1,1); 
INSERT INTO orders VALUES (10,2,5,1,2);
```

From the above I need to identify thingamabob customers who only purchased widgets and purchased more in the latest period versus prior.

I have written the below query:

```
WITH otherprod AS (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN product p
ON o.product_id=p.product_id 
WHERE category_name='thingamabobs' AND o.product_id<>1 ),
prod AS (SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
FROM orders o
WHERE o.product_id=1 
),
solus AS (SELECT p.customer_id
FROM prod p
LEFT JOIN otherprod op
ON p.customer_id=op.customer_id
),
prodpp AS (SELECT customer_id,SUM(sales) AS ppsales
FROM orders o
WHERE o.product_id=1 
AND date_id<2
GROUP BY customer_id
),
prodtp AS (SELECT customer_id,SUM(sales) AS sales
FROM orders o
WHERE o.product_id=1 
AND date_id>1
GROUP BY customer_id
)
SELECT pp.customer_id
FROM prodpp pp
INNER JOIN prodtp tpp
ON pp.customer_id=tpp.customer_id
INNER JOIN solus s
ON pp.customer_id=s.customer_id
WHERE ppsales<sales;
```

Which returns the correct result:

### customer_id

```
       5
       1
```

(2 rows)

But is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write the query something like this:

```
select customer_id,
       sum(case when date_id = 1 then sales else 0 end) as sales_1,
       sum(case when date_id = 2 then sales else 0 end) as sales_2
from (select o.*, p.*,
             min(p.product_name) over (partition by o.customer_id) as minpn,
             max(p.product_name) over (partition by o.customer_id) as maxpn
      from orders o join
           products p
           on o.product_id = p.product_id
      where p.category_name = 'thingamabobs'
     ) op
where minpn = maxpn and minpn = 'widget'
group by custoemr_id
having sales_2 > sales_1;
```

This is based off of your description, not your code.

Notes:

- The subquery calculates the minimum and maximum product for each customer in the "thingamabobs" group.
- They are the same when the minimum and maximum are the same and they have the value you are looking at.
- I don't follow the date logic, for conversion from dates to periods.  Perhaps there should be more sophisticated date logic in the outer `case` expressions.

Comment: Thanks, but I am running Postgres and it does not appear happy with your code.  I am getting the below error.

 ERROR:  column "sales_2" does not exist
LINE 14: having sales_2 > sales_1;
                ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "op.sales".
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "sales_2" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "op.sales".
Character: 557